# DOM and JavaScript Engine used in Office365 Thick Clients

Tags: javascript, office365

The product I work on offers SSO into Office365, through both the web and native, "thick" clients aka rich clients. Part of SSO-ing into an Office365 app, such as Excel for example, involves displaying my product's login page inside of the login popup window inside the thick client. The problem is, only on Windows, I get many JavaScript errors when trying to execute the JavaScript included in our login page (it happens to be using AngularJS, but I suspect many frameworks/libraries would be incompatible). It appears that `console` is not supported, along with `document.body`, and many other "essentials".

Does anyone have any knowledge of the DOM and script engines that are used here? The first page shown in the SSO flow is Microsoft's login page where you enter your email address, which then redirects to my product's login page (mapped by domain on the email address), and their page seems to render fine, so clearly it's possible to get HTML and JS to work nice (enough). I'd also take a recommendation on any kind of shim/polyfill that would help me get moving, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more digging, it looks like I was able to solve my problem by specifying an HTTP Response header of name `X-UA-Compatible` with value `IE=edge`, which tells IE to render using the latest document standards. It looked like the web view was originally trying to render using IE7 compatibility mode, which explains why none of my JS was working as intended.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/3822733 for more information on `X-UA-Compatible`, this is the question/answer that helped me solve this problem.